# Which distributions cannot be captured using this representation of the joint probability?

Tags: probability

Reading through *Probabilistic Graphical Models*, I came across this definition along with an accompanying statement.

> Let $P(x_i) = \theta_i$.
>
> Define:
>
> $$P(x_1, \ldots , x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n \theta_i$$
>
> This representation is limited, and there are many distributions that
>   we cannot capture by choosing values for $\theta_i, \ldots, \theta_n$.
>   This fact is obvious not only from intuition, but also from a somewhat
>   more formal perspective. The space of all joint distributions is a $2^n - 1$
>   dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2^n}$ - the set $\{ (p_1, \ldots , p_{2^n}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2^n} : p_1 + \cdots + p_{2^n} = 1 \}$ .

It is not obvious or intuitive to me that there are many distributions that cannot be captured by choosing values for $\theta_i, \ldots, \theta_n$. What sort of distribution could not be captured this way? One with continuous values?

Comment: Every non-product measure. Example: $P(x,y)=(x+y)/4$ for every $x$ and $y$ in $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @Did thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I seem to be missing some sort of foundational understanding of this. I do not know what I should be asking myself to see why this cannot be captured. Why is this the case?

Comment: Assume that $P(x,y)=\theta_x\theta_y$ for every $(x,y)$ in $\{0,1\}$ then $\theta_0^2=(0+0)/4=0$, $\theta_0\theta_1=(0+1)/4=1/4$ and $\theta_1^2=(1+1)/4=1/2$, contradiction. And yet $P$ is a legitimate probability distribution on $\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}$ since $\sum\limits_{x,y}P(x,y)=0/4+1/4+1/4+2/4=1$.

Comment: OK I think I understand. When you state that $P(x, y) = (x + y)/4$, it can easily be shown (as you did) that it contradicts the original definition $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. That's all there is to it?

Answer (score 1):

Any distribution that has correlation between some variables should suffice to give a counter-example. For example, consider the classical family of Gaussian/normal distributions whose probability density function is proportional to $e^{-x^T K^{-1} x}$ for a positive definite symmetric matrix $K$ and vector of variables $x$. Just through basic matrix computations, it's fairly easy to see that you cannot represent this distribution in your graphical model form (as a product of marginal distributions as you described) unless $K$ is a diagonal matrix. This also contributes to the secondary comment that the number of degrees of freedom for a distribution is greater than for a product distribution you described, because obviously you have a lot more degrees of freedom (dimensionality) in specifying a positive definite matrix than just specifying a positive diagonal matrix.

Comment: It is going to take me some time to digest this answer, but I have a few immediate thoughts. I do not fully understand what it means for the probability density function to be proportional to $e^{-x^TK^{-1}x}$. Or rather, why is that important? Is it because that density function would not exist in $\mathbb{R}^{2^n}$ for a positive definite symmetrix matrix $K$? I can see that if $K$ is a diagonal matrix, then the probability density function is in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is this correct?